# Allow only digits and a specific word in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write regular expression (or a test using jQuery) that allows only digits and a specific word.

For example (the word "**Hello**" is allowd):

- 123Hello => valid
- hello => valid
- 123 => valid
- hello word => invalid
- he123llo => invalid
- he llo 123 => invalid

Thank you in advance

Comment: Would '123hello123' or 'hello123hello' be valid? Should spaces between the number and 'hello' be allowed (e.g. 'hello 123' or '123 hello')?

Comment: The regex that gives your example: `^\d*(?:hello|Hello)?\d*$` https://regex101.com/r/Om1oX6/1

Comment: '123hello123' and 'hello123hello' are valides and the spaces too are allowed

Comment: @Sara The updated pattern based on that `hello` may occur multiple times, might be this: `^\d*(?:(?:hello)?\d*)*$`

Comment: I add `^(?:(?:[Hh]ello|\d+)\s*)+$` to the pool. Regular expressions are descriptions of patterns. Since OP didn't describe the pattern and only gave very few select examples of valid and invalid values, this entire question is guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the following simple pattern should work for you:

```
^\d*(?:hello)?\d*$
```

You may use the regex in case insensitive mode.  Example:

```js
var inputs = ["123Hello", "hello", "123", "hello word", "he123llo", "he llo 123"];
inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    if (/^\d*(?:hello)?\d*$/i.test(input)) {
        console.log(input + ": VALID");
    }
    else {
        console.log(input + ": INVALID");
    }
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't this RE match also an empty string?

Comment: @secan Yes, it would, but the OP didn't mention this edge case one way or the other.  A quick fix would be to just add `(?=.)` to the very start of the pattern, to assert at least one character present, but before I edit I would rather wait for feedback from the OP.

Comment: Yes, the OP left out quite a few cases.

Comment: @Sara, I am a bit confused; if the strings '123hello123' and 'hello123hello' should be considered valid and space between the numbers and 'hello' should be allowed, as per your reply to my comment, than you cannot use this RegExp as it will reject '123hello123', 'hello123hello','123 hello 123', 'hello 123 hello' and many other valid combinations.